# PostgresQL - define SEQUENCE for a SELECT query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sequence

I have a `VIEW` for which I use a certain `SELECT` statement, where there is a `CASE` condition, which, based on some condition being TRUE or FALSE decides, whether to increment the counter or use the current value.

As far as I know, any view of a `SELECT` statement is generated every time it is referenced, so I would like to recreate the `SEQUENCE` every time that happens.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE num(
n BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO num(n) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9);

CREATE TEMP SEQUENCE seq START 1;
SELECT nextval('seq');

SELECT 
CASE WHEN n % 2 = 0 THEN nextval('seq')
     ELSE currval('seq')
END AS test,
n
FROM num;
```

I had to insert `SELECT nextval('seq')` before the `SELECT` statement, otherwise it yielded

```
ERROR:  currval of sequence "seq" is not yet defined in this session
```

And at the end of the day this code doesn't recreate the `SEQUENCE` each time, as it would only use the created one to generate new values.

This chunk of code works as expected, but smells like bad database design from my side.

Would any one of you guys know, how to create a new `SEQUENCE` object every time the `SELECT` is called? Or is there another way? I feel like there should be a clean and clear way of doing that, and I'm surely missing out on something!

Comment: Depending on how this is used, you would get an increment for every *row* in the view, not once per view.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tried explaining better and provided a minimal working example. Please, check the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example, you can set the value of the sequence in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN n % 2 = 0 THEN nextval('seq')
             ELSE currval('seq')
        END) AS test,
       n
FROM num CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT setval('seq', 1)) s;
```

The `FROM` clause should be evaluated before the outer `SELECT`, so the outer `SELECT` should start at the specified value.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b28b2152524c26389452a85eaf1a6217) is a db<>fiddle.

I should note that this does suggest a problem with the database design.  However, I could imagine a view containing:

```
FROM (SELECT NEXT_VALUE('view_cnt')) x CROSS JOIN
     . . .
```

To count the number of times the view has been called.  That might be handy information.

Comment: doesn't cross join require too many operations? Because from the looks of it it maps every value of set A to every value of set B. How is it possible, since B (the sequence) is virtually infinite?

Comment: @winwin . . . You are misunderstanding the code.  The subquery gets executed once (because it is in the `FROM` clause).  It returns one row.  That row is then "cross joined" to the rest of the query.  However, it doesn't do much except to make the just-calculated column available.  But because it is not used, it really has no effect.